# what is wrong with my calculateSum function in java because it return ZERO

Tags: java, for-loop, sum, multidimensional-array

i am trying to calculate the sum of elements after the diagonal in 2D array but the problem is that the sum is always equal ZERO it do not change the answer.

where is the mistake in my code and how to fix it ?

i tried to use nested for loop and o tried to use one for loop but in both cases th eanswer still 0.

**this is my code:**

```
package test8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2 {

    private int row = 4;
    private int col = 4;
    private int[][] matrix;

    public Question2(int trow, int tcol) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
    }

    public Question2(int trow, int tcol, int[][] m) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
        this.matrix = m;
    }

    public int[][] fill() {
        int[][] data = new int[row][col];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.println("enter the elementss for the Matrix");
                data[row][col] = in.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(data[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public int calculate(int[][] num) {

        int sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < num.length; row++) {
            //for (int col = row + 1; col < num[row].length; col++) {
                // if(row == col){
                System.out.println(row);
                sum += num[row][row];
                // }
            //}

        }
         System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
        return sum;
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

    Question2 q2 = new Question2(3, 3);
    int[][] ma = q2.fill();
    q2.calculate(ma);
   }
}
```

**this is the output:**

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
0
1
2
the sum is: 15
```

Comment: Most likely the array you are summing is full of zeros, i.e. not the one you printed out.

Comment: @java dev show your array

Comment: ok i will edit my question and display the hole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that in your `fill` method you are creating local `data` array, which is filled with values and returned as result, but in your `main` method you are not storing this array anywhere. Instead in `calculate` you are using `int[][] ma = new int[3][3];` which is filled with `0`.

So maybe change your code to something like

```
Question2 q2 = new Question2(3, 3);// you don't even need to pass array here if you 
                                   // plan to generate new one, so consider removing 
                                   // array from argument list in this constructor
int[][] ma = q2.fill();//store array with elements in `ma` reference
q2.calculate(ma);      //now `ma` has elements so we can do some calculations
```

Anyway your code seems strange. It looks like you want your class to store some array, but you are not using this array anywhere (except in `fill` method where you are using its `length` properties to fill `data` array - which seems wrong since `data` can have different size than `matrix`).
Maybe in `fill` method you shouldn't be creating new `data` array, but instead you should fill `matrix` array? Also in that case you don't need to pass this array as argument in constructor, but just create new array based on `row` and `col` values.
This way you will not even need `calculate` method to get any array from outside, just use `matrix` field.

In other words your code can look more like

```
// remove entirely this constructor, you will not need it
public Question2(int trow, int tcol, int[][] m) {

    this.row = trow;
    this.col = tcol;
    this.matrix = m;
}

// but use only this one
public Question2(int trow, int tcol) {
    this.row = trow;
    this.col = tcol;
    this.matrix = new int[trow,tcol];// just make sure it will initialize `matrix`
}
```

Now you can simply use `new Question2(3,3)` and be sure that it will also have empty array with correct sizes.

Time for `fill` method. Don't create local `int[][] data` array, just use `matrix` instead, so change

```
data[row][col] = in.nextInt();
```

to

```
matrix[row][col] = in.nextInt();
```

Last thing is `calculate` method. You don't need it to actually take any array from user, because you already have `matrix` array inside your class so you can simply reuse it. So instead of `calculate(int[][] num)` make it `calculate()` and instead of `num` use `matrix`.

So now your code can look like

```
Question2 q2 = new Question2(3, 3);
q2.fill();
q2.calculate();
```

Comment: if i changed my main method to your solution i will get an error of **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: @javadev That is because in your `fill` method instead of `data.length` you are using `matrix.length`, but matrix is not set (it is `null` so it has no methods or fields like *length*). Your code seems little strange because you are not actually using `matrix` anywhere. What is the point of even having such field?

Comment: sorry for the mistake i changed the name of the array without deleting **matrix** now it work it return the answer of sum but still not the correct answer how to fix it ??

Comment: i edit my question and display the changed code with the output

Comment: @javadev You shouldn't change code in your question this drastically because it makes posted answers looks like they are not answering your original question. You can add new example with information that it is update, but never change entire question.

Comment: Anyway I updated my answer a little with alternative approach which should solve your problem.

Comment: my calculate function it calculate the sum of elements of the diagonal what i want is to calculate the sum of elements after the diagonal

Comment: ohh sorry i thought that will be easier to you and others to trace the updated question

Comment: What do you mean by *i want is to calculate the sum of elements after the diagonal*? Your question never mentioned anything about it.

Comment: so if i am asking this question it will be better to create a new question ?? and thank you for your help

Comment: If you feel that your edit will change one question into entirely different one (like "why is this code not working" into "how do I add this new functionality to my project") then it is better to create separate question.

Comment: But if you are going to refer in your next question to the previous one, make sure that your previous question was answered correctly and you used solution posted there.

Comment: sir i thank you for your help i solved my problem using nested for loop thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple structure problem but, responding your question, replace this line:

```
q2.fill();
```

by:

```
ma = q2.fill();
```

Comment: why i have to  replace q2.fill() by ma = q2.fill()? in my main method i fill the q2 with the ma it does not make since to make ma = q2.fill()