# Java 2d array matrix program

Tags: java, arrays

```java
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        if(j%2>=i) // I think the problem is this
            even += twoD[i][j];
        else
            if(i%2!>=j) // I think the problem is this
                odd += twoD[j][i];
    }
}
System.out.println("The sum of the even elements above the diagonal is: "+even);
System.out.println("The sum of the odd elements below the diagonal is: "+odd);
```

This is the code I am working with. The problem is it doesn't display the real sum of the elements above and below as I'd want in a diagonal. The matrix is basically randomized so I had to check it everytime to verify the sum.

Comment: The sum should also be odd or even only but the output is different and i don't where did that number came from.

Comment: for curiosity, in this (i%2!>=j) you try check 2 factorial or the negative of 2 module are gretter than j

Comment: Can you please provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also not really clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Even numbers are those where `number%2==0` is true. Odd numbers are those where that same condition is false. I don't know what you are trying to do in the conditions of your ifs, but it's not what you want to do.

Comment: That is not valid java code. `i%2!>=j` doesn't make sense in java. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: I would say that this question has been asked before. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656935/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-elements-after-the-diagonal-in-2d-array-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the elements *above* the diagonal `j > i` (index of column is always greater than that of the row); for the elements below `j < i`.

Then the loops may be optimized slightly to provide `j > i` and swapping indexes for elements below the matrix diagonal:

```java
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
for(int i=0; i<twoD.length; i++) {
    for(int j=i + 1; j<twoD[i].length; j++) {
        if(twoD[i][j] %2 == 0) {
            even += twoD[i][j];
        }
        if(twoD[j][i] %2 != 0) {  // swap indexes below diagonal
            odd += twoD[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you've thought, the conditions are incorrect. Actually I'm not sure what was the logic behind them.
What you need to do is to find whether given number is above or below diagonal. You can do that by comparing indicies themselves - `j>i` and `j<i`.
Only then you need to check if a given number (not index) is odd or even - `twoD[i][j] % 2 == 0`.

Something like so should get the job done:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        if(j>i && twoD[i][j]%2==0){
           even += twoD[i][j];
        }
        if(j<i && twoD[i][j]%2!=0){
           odd += twoD[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but the code for the odd elements is still wrong, meaning it doesn't output the real sum of the odd elements below the diagonal.